# Is PEX water piping allowed in San Francisco?

Tags: water, pex

I’m sorry if this is inappropriate to ask so specifically for San Francisco dwellers, but I couldn’t find the answer this online.  Does anyone know if PEX plumbing is allowed for water piping solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like San Francisco uses an [amended version of the 2015 Uniform Plumbing Code (UPC)](http://library.amlegal.com/nxt/gateway.dll/California/sfbuilding/sanfranciscobuildinginspectioncommission?f=templates$fn=default.htm$3.0$vid=amlegal:sanfrancisco_ca$sync=1). So as long as the PEX conforms to NSF 61 and has the marking "NSF-61" or "NSF pw", it should be allowed.  A quick call to the San Francisco building department, should provide a definitive answer.